# Objective-C: Singleton

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I'm trying to make a singleton but I keep running into an error and am not sure what I am doing wrong:

Here's my .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ColorMaker : NSObject { 

}

+(ColorMaker* )sharedColorMaker;

- (UIColor* ) setColor : (float) red : (float) green : (float) blue; 

@end
```

Here's the .m

```
#import "ColorMaker.h"

@implementation ColorMaker

+(ColorMaker *)sharedColorMaker { 

static ColorMaker* sharedColorMaker;

@synchronized(self) { 

    if (!sharedColorMaker)

        sharedColorMaker = [[ColorMaker alloc] init];

    return sharedColorMaker;

}

}

- (UIColor* ) setColor:(float)red :(float)green :(float)blue {

float newRed = red/255;
float newGreen = green/255;
float newBlue = blue/255;

UIColor* colorToReturn = [UIColor colorWithRed:newRed green:newGreen blue:newBlue alpha:1.0];

return colorToReturn;    
}

@end
```

in viewcontroller, viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
[super viewDidUnload];

ColorMaker* thisColorMaker = [ColorMaker sharedColorMaker];
}
```

keep getting "Use of undeclared identifier ColorMaker" error.

Comment: Import ColorMaker.h in the view controller's .m file?

Comment: Your code is textbook-clean, you're just missing an import.

Comment: BTW, what is the point of your singleton anyway...?  You might as well add your method as a UIColor category.

Comment: @PM/das - I figured that out, which meant I was confused on singletons, I thought a singleton would not need to be imported. If I want to use it in another class do I also have to import it there as well?

Comment: @tap - good tip, the point of it was to just figure out how to use a singleton, but in retrospect a category makes more sense.

Comment: Yes you have to import the class where ever you are using it whether singleton or normal classes. To avoid rewriting import in all the classes you can import this singleton class in `.pch` file.

Comment: IKR - well, where's the magic in that. : D

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input.

Comment: This is the best example I've seen of doing a singleton. Especially the comment by ArvinB. It's able to be reused by several different classes, cleanly. https://gist.github.com/1057420